# Get text from XML data without using domxpath

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have stored all XML data into single cell of single column named `Content`.

Here's the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
    <record>
        <language>eng</language>
        <publisher>Molecular Diversity Preservation International</publisher>
        <journalTitle>Dentistry Journal</journalTitle>
        <eissn>2304-6767</eissn>
        <publicationDate>2012-06-19</publicationDate>
        <volume>1</volume>
        <issue>1</issue>
        <startPage>1</startPage>
        <endPage>2</endPage>
        <doi>10.3390/dj1010001</doi>
        <publisherRecordId>dj1010001</publisherRecordId>
        <documentType>article</documentType>
        <title language="eng">
        Dentistry ― At the Heart of Conflict between Medicine and Technology</title>
        <authors>
            <author>
                <name>Claude Jaquiery</name>
                <email>jaquieryc@uhbs.ch</email>
                <affiliationId>1</affiliationId>
            </author>
        </authors>
        <affiliationsList>
            <affiliationName affiliationId="1">Department of Cranio-Maxillofacial Surgery and Hightech Research Center, University Hospital Basel, Spitalstrasse 21, 4031 Basel, Switzerland</affiliationName>
        </affiliationsList>
        <abstract language="eng">As the first Editor-in-Chief of Dentistry Journal, I would like to provide a few comments about this field of research and practice. Evolved from a purely technical profession, dentists are nowadays exposed to a variety of different challenges. [...]</abstract>
        <fullTextUrl format="pdf">http://www.mdpi.com/2304-6767/1/1/1</fullTextUrl>
        <keywords language="eng">
            <keyword>n/a</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </record>
    <record>
        <language>eng</language>
        <publisher>Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute</publisher>
        <journalTitle>Dentistry Journal</journalTitle>
        <eissn>2304-6767</eissn>
        <publicationDate>2012-12-21</publicationDate>
        <volume>1</volume>
        <issue>1</issue>
        <startPage>3</startPage>
        <endPage>11</endPage>
        <doi>10.3390/dj1010003</doi>
        <publisherRecordId>dj1010003</publisherRecordId>
        <documentType>article</documentType>
        <title language="eng">Color Parameters of the Chromascop Shade Guide</title>
        <authors>
            <author>
                <name>William J. O&#039;Brien</name>
                <email>ohws@umich.edu</email>
                <affiliationId>1</affiliationId>
            </author>
            <author>
                <name>Won-Suk Oh</name>
                <email>ohws@umich.edu</email>
                <affiliationId>1</affiliationId>
            </author>
            <author>
                <name>Peter W. Piché</name>
                <email>drppiche@gmail.com</email>
                <affiliationId>2</affiliationId>
            </author>
        </authors>
        <affiliationsList>
            <affiliationName affiliationId="1">Dept of Biologic &amp; Materials Sciences, University of Michigan School of Dentistry, 1011 North University, Ann Arbor, MI 48109, USA</affiliationName>
            <affiliationName affiliationId="2">Private Practice, 335 E State St Traverse City, MI 49684, USA</affiliationName>
        </affiliationsList>
        <abstract language="eng">The purposes of this study are: (1) determine the color of the twenty shades in the Ivoclar’s Chromascop shade guide, (2) determine the color representation of the shade guide described as coverage error (CE), and (3) compare this shade guide with the Vita Classical and Bioform shade guides. The spectral data was collected using Beckman model DU reflectance spectrophotometer equipped with an integrating sphere. Commission International de l’Eclairage (CIE) chromaticity coordinates were calculated using CIE illuminant C and 1931 observer data, then converted to CIE L*a*b* and Munsell notation. Each shade was spectrophotometrically compared to the published colors of 335 human teeth. The minimum CIE L*a*b* color difference was calculated for each tooth and the average of these color differences was defined as the CE. The measured colors of the Chromascop guide had a CIE L* range of 79.67 to 65.61, an a* range of -0.71 to 3.85, and a b* range of 14.58 to 27.69. The average CE of the Chromascop shade guide was 3.38. The Chromascop shade guide has similar colors and a CE compared with the Bioform and Vita Classical shade guides, but with some shades of higher red and yellow components.</abstract>
        <fullTextUrl format="pdf">http://www.mdpi.com/2304-6767/1/1/3</fullTextUrl>
        <keywords language="eng">
            <keyword>tooth color</keyword>
            <keyword> Chromascop shade guide</keyword>
            <keyword>coverage error</keyword>
        </keywords>
    </record>
</records>
```

Here is how I want to fetch text from this XML data into a div :

**PHP code**:

```
while($runrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{

$id = $runrows['id'];
$name = $runrows['name'];

 $content = $runrows['content'];//this contains all xml data corresponds to each id 

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("$content");
  foreach($doc->children() as $book)
  {    
   echo $language = $book->record[0]->language;
   $journalTitle = $book->record[0]->journalTitle;
  $publicationDate = $book->record[0]->publicationDate;
  }


echo "<div  > 
id :&nbsp;$id<br>
filename :&nbsp;$name<br>
echo  $language." <br />";
echo $journalTitle ." <br />";
echo $publicationDate ." <br />";
echo "</div>";
 }
```

I want to fetch text directly from the contents stored in my database without using domxpath is this possible..??

Comment: why? whats wrong with using an XML parser? how are you going to parse values without them? thats why they're there in the first place

Comment: I didn't use it yet but maybe this is interesting: [MySQL XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html)

Comment: see this link ""https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/427263/extract-data-from-an-xml-file-and-display-it-in-php""  in this example  $xml = simplexml_load_file("books.xml"); is use , and I used  $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("$content"); instead so why isnt it possible without xpath ..???

Comment: What does your question have to do with XPath _at all_? Looks like you simply want to loop over all first-level children of your XML data, and output certain child element contents … so, what is your _specific_ problem with that? (Using a foreach loop that way – _overwriting_ variables in it, and only outputting the content of those variables once after the loop – doesn’t make the most sense. You have one `echo` statement in there, but that rather looks like copy&pasted from the example you are referring to, than to be deliberately placed there.)

Comment: It is possible without XPath, The DOM document/nodes have methods like getElementsByTagName() and the returned nodes have properties like $nodeValue. But why? It is a lot more work.

Comment: @commentators: as I understand the question he wants to extract the values with mySQL, not via PHP

Comment: that was my mistake sorry i forgot to remove that echo statement it's not copied its just a small reference from my project @CBore

Comment: I just want a simple way for extracting values from xml data with out using domxpath as given in this link .But the difference is just that he's extracting from a file and i am extracting from whole data stored in a single cell ...plz tell me how this can be done ....??

Comment: What do you mean by cell ? Have you stored XML data in Excel or DB ?